# Sitecore User Group Brazil - May 22, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time BRT: Tuesday, May 22, 2018, Starts at 7:00 PM

Date/Time EST: Tuesday, May 22, 2018, Starts at 6:00 PM

Date/Time UTC: Tuesday, May 22, 2018, Starts at 22:00 PM

RSVP: http://meetu.ps/e/FfcRS/yrwpQ/f

Join us @Florianopolis, Tuesday May 22, 2018 for our next Brazil Sitecore User Group (SUGBR).

Presentations

- Is it time to migrate to Sitecore Forms by João Neto (Sitecore MVP 2018)
- GDPR + Sitecore by Daniel Roberge (VP of IT Strategy and Integration for North America for Valtech) and Vinicius Deschamps (Sitecore MVP 2017-2018)

Comment: Done. Community promotion has begun.